# Cannot connect to azure database using raspberry pi

Tags: azure, raspberry-pi, azure-sql-database

I am using Azure SQL database service. I want to test the connection using my Raspberry Pi but I always get this error:

[image: error image]

I have already setup the firewall and want to access the database.

i am following [this tutorial](http://mdupont.com/Blog/Raspberry-Pi/azure-python3.html).

Note: I have already setup firewall access rule for my IP.

Comment: The error clearly states your IP address is not set up in the firewall. Maybe edit your question to clarify how you added your IP address? (without specifically giving away your personal info)

Comment: I would suggest you do the following:1. double check your firewall settings on Azure portal. 2. double check your configuration files especially freetds.conf